Web Components and Angular 18
What are the Changes form Angular 17 to 18 for Web Components (Standalone Elements)?
I've tried some Angular 17 related Guides / couldn't find any (usefull) information about the changes for 18 so far.
My Setup
main.ts:
import {createApplication} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {createCustomElement} from "@angular/elements";
import {GridWidgetComponent} from "./app/grid-widget/grid-widget.component";

(async () => {
    const app = await createApplication({
        providers: []
    });

    const gridElement = createCustomElement(GridWidgetComponent, {
        injector: app.injector,
    });

    customElements.define("grid-widget", gridElement);
})();

PHP Storm informs me in my main.ts that: "Expression statement is not assignment or call"
index-test.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<grid-widget></grid-widget>
<script src="component-lib.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>

script linked as type=module because there was a message for Syntax Error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at component-lib.js:3:144) but changed nothing
src/app/grid-widget/grid-widget.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'grid-widget',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './grid-widget.component.html',
  styleUrl: './grid-widget.component.scss'
})
export class GridWidgetComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}

angular.json:
...
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/webcomponent-example",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
...

package.json:
...
 "build": "ng build --output-hashing=none --configuration production",
 "package" : "npm run build && cat dist/webcomponent-example/{polyfills,main}.js > dist/component-lib.js",
...
"dependencies":{
...
"@angular/elements": "^18.2.1",
...
"@angular/platform-browser": "^18.1.0",
...
}

The result is an error in the console that "Nt" already has been declared:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Nt' has already been declared" when using type=module without type=module I've got a Syntax Error about the Export:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"
One of the tutorials I've used was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDf4PFC_Vok&t=508s
In the docs I've only found https://angular.dev/guide/elements but it does not show how to build it correctly.
Target is to have a Web Component (obviously for a grid and later others too) which can be embedded into a PHP site. Because there could be multiple instances on the same page I tough WebComponents / Elements would be a working solution.
Did anyone got a good reference on how to create Web Components with Angular 18?

There were basically no changes around them. Your issue seems elsewhere as you getting duplicated symbols generated when mangling is enabled.

Ok I've found the issue - The problem relied on the bundler Script which should combine polyfills.js and main.js into one "bundle.js" file:
...
"package": "npm run build && cat dist/widgets/browser/{polyfills,main}.js > dist/widgets/browser/bundle.js",
...

When using polyfills.js and main.js there is no issue and everything works like a charm.

Thanks. I'm not quite sure bundling polyfills.js is a good idea, as you might want to load multiple web components but only load polyfills.js once
